# Electron with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am writing desktop app with Electron from Github, and I am using React with it. One thing I notice is that because Electron uses io.js, I no longer need webpack to build my code like when I dev for client-side web app. However, I still need something that can load JSX. I am using Babel request hook, but it seems a little slow. I don't really need the ES6 features in Babel since they are supported in io.js.

Is there another way I can use JSX with Electron?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Webpack is actually designed with Electron development in mind. What I need to do is to to specify in the `webpack.config.js` file is config `target: 'atom'`. Webpack will know that it is packaging an Atom (now known as Electron) app, and will not attempt to bundle packages such as `fs`, or any modules in `node_modules`. With webpack, I can configure babel to my heart desire, and I also get minification.

#### Update

As @eduludi has mentioned, the value for target is now `electron`.

Comment: Could you give me a example of webpack config file ?

Comment: Looks like atom was replaced by electron as target value. See here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target